# Insert markers with different icon from my list drawable

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to add marker on map with long click. but it is not working. normal click is working.
This is my code.

public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

```
GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
    if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        finish();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
    // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
    googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
 // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

 // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
 // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
 // Getting the name of the best provider
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    if (location != null) {
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);


}



@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    TextView locationTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlongLocation);
 // Getting latitude of the current location
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("you are here" ));
    // Showing the current location in Google Map
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    // Zoom in the Google Map
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(5));
 // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
    locationTv.setText("Latitude:" + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude);
}

public void onMapClick (LatLng point) {
    // Do Something
    googleMap =
    ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap)).getMap();
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(point)
    .title("TouchPoint"));
}
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(
            point.toString()));

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "New marker added@" + point.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
        return true;
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
        return false;
    }
}





@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate

```
googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(longClickListener);
```

Inside the activity

```
private OnMapLongClickListener longClickListener = new OnMapLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
      //do work }
}
```

Comment: when i add googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(longClickListener); in onCreate i had a erreur it seems longClickListener cannot be resolved to a variable